# Multiple Auth Providers Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have LoginActivity with Email/password login, facebook, google authentication. It works separately but if I create account with google, I can't login with facebook.

Login activity code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mLogin,mRegister;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN =0;
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    public FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private TextView facebookRegister;
    private SignInButton googleSignIn;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginTest.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //FACEBOOK
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        googleSignIn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        googleSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });

        firebaseAuthStateListener= new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null){
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };


        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);



        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                handleFacebookToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                   //fill database
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logInEmailPassword();

            }
        });

        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
    }



    private void logInEmailPassword() {
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        if(email.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mEmail.setError("Enter email!");
        };
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            mPassword.setError("Enter password!");
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
            AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
            linkWithCredential(credential);
        }
    }

    private void handleFacebookToken(AccessToken token) {

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        linkWithCredential(credential);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            FirebaseGoogleAuth(account);
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w("myLog", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());;
        }
    }

    private void FirebaseGoogleAuth(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
        linkWithCredential(authCredential);
        }
    private void linkWithCredential(AuthCredential credential){

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        //mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
             mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("myLog", "linkWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            Log.w("myLog", "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    }
```

I've followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking?authuser=0 tutorial but I stuck at linkWithCredential.
Can you help me fix that issue? Thanks

Comment: Why do you say "I can't login with facebook"? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Well,no errors. It stops at "Authentication failed." 
The problem if that user exists in Firebase Authentication already and is assigned to GoogleAuth i cant login with Facebook.
It works vice versa, if facebook user exists in firebase and i login with google it overrides that user
Register :Google --->>>>logout >>>>>login:Facebook >>>>dont work 
but
Register :Facebook--->>>logout >>>>>login:Google >>>>> works

Answer (score 0):

The problem if that user exists in Firebase Authentication already and is assigned to GoogleAuth i cant login with Facebook.
It works vice versa, if facebook user exists in firebase and i login with google it overrides that user.

```
Register ---- logout ---- login
Google --->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Facebook >>>>dont work
Facebook--->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Google >>>>> works
```

Comment: Yes it's an exception that firebase authentication makes it allows a single mail to login into firebase. It allows to reduce spamming into firebase. But if you want same logins into different auth providers. Then go to authentication page in firebase and find multiple accounts for same email settings and enable it.

Comment: Yes I know that but it creates extra user. I need to connect one user with multiple login auth.